# Plotting Complicated Region in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, regions

I'm trying to plot the region corresponding to the following code. The f[0,0,5] lines were just me testing the functions. When its plotted, the region only shows the first part of my region plot ($y\geq \frac{1-\beta}{1-\alpha}x$. The second part does not show up and I can not tell if that is due to an error in the code or simply it is too complicated for Mathematica to compute. Does the code look correct? [image]

```
f[alpha_,beta_,s2_]:= NSolve[{s2-p+beta(p-5alpha )==(G1[p-5 alpha])/(g1[p-5alpha]),0<=p<=10},p]
g1[p_]:= PDF[NormalDistribution[5,1],p]
G1[p_]:= CDF[NormalDistribution[5,1],p]
f[alpha_,beta_,s2_]:= Nsolve[{s2-p+beta(p-5alpha )==(G1[p-5 alpha])/(g1[p-5alpha]),0<=p<=10},p]
s2star=(1/2)(10+Sqrt[2Pi])
Manipulate[RegionPlot[{y >=((1-beta)/(1-alpha))x,x<=If[y>=s2star,f[alpha,beta,y]-alpha(f[alpha,beta,y]-beta(f[alpha,beta,y]-5alpha )+(G1[f[alpha,beta,y]-5alpha ])/(g1[f[alpha,beta,y]-5alpha ])),f[alpha,beta,y]-alpha(5-((g1[s2star])/G1[s2star]))]},
        {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}],{beta,-2,2,0.1},{alpha,-2,2,0.1}]
```

Comment: Post your code rather than a picture of it so that it can be copied and pasted into a notebook.

Comment: Just added the code

Comment: Noticed typo above:  NSolve not Nsolve